# The difference between RNN Decoder and RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, sequence-to-sequence

We are only using the RNN decoder (without encoder) for text generation, how is RNN decoder different from pure RNN operation?

RNN Decoder in TensorFlow: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/dynamic_rnn_decoder

Pure RNN in TensorFlow: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

RNN Decoder is sequence to sequence mapping model. In combination with Encoder takes a sequence as input and generates another sequence as output. In many to many sequence learning setups, **the input is a sequence of vectors and the output is another sequence of vectors**.

**Eg: Speech Wave to Text, Language Translation etc**

In General We use Normal RNN for **one to one sequence learning setup**.

**Eg: Next Character Prediction.**